# Date.now() on server in advance relative to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, client

Here is my situation:

I have a client connected to a server with Node.js, socket.io.

If I calculate Date.now() on server, send it to the client, and then make the client print the time received from the server and it's own Date.now() I get a very strange result: The server time is 514ms bigger than the client time. But logically the server Date.now() has to happen before the client-one.

I don't understand what is happening here. Does the server calculate Date.now() differently than the client because of its time zone ? Is something else happening ?

Comment: You are assuming both clocks, the client and server one, have the "correct" time. Most of the time this is not the case.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder to upvote and "accept" (the green checkmark) an answer if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: Of course, sorry, not used to post questions on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is called clock skew.  Like any clock, the clock inside a computer has to be set to the correct time, and the clocks for any two computers slowly diverge from one another.  Therefore, it's almost certain that any two computers will think its a slightly different time.  Usually, this difference is small enough that you don't notice, but it can be big enough to see it when you deliberately run an experiment like the one you just did.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! So i have no certitude that other computers will see the same time difference client-server, since every-one will have it's own time ? I suppose i have to make a test for every client that connects to be sure ?

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to use try to sequence important events by using the computer's clock: especially when doing any kind of distributed computing.

Comment: Ok, i created a quick fix by calculating the time difference. So if i'm dealing with a multiplayer game, i should create an artificial game-time and use this to do all my calculations ? (interpolation, in this case).

Comment: I'm no expert in games, but that certainly sounds like a reasonable approach.  I expect a lot has been written on the subject which may prove useful. Here's [one example](https://web.eecs.utk.edu/~huangj/netgames/notes/synch.html) to start with.